# React Native : my component isn't detected as a component

Tags: react-native, components

I'm started with React Native and try to use the navigation between screns. To do so I creat a component Navigation but when I want to use it this error show up :

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined
```

It appear to be the component AppNavigator that is the issue

I tried :

- checked all my exports and import and for me their is no problems
- change my const component in a function component but nothing do the trick.

Can you help me ?

App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppNavigator from './components/navigation';

function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <AppNavigator />
    </View>
  );
}


/*const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});*/

export default App;
```

Navigation.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigatorContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Localisation from './localisation';
import Home from './home';

const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator()

const AppNavigator = () => (
  <NavigatorContainer>
    <Navigator  initialRouteName="Home">
      <Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Home" component={Home} />
    </Navigator>
  </NavigatorContainer>
 
)

export default AppNavigator;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no component named `NavigatorContainer` in `react-navigation/native`. The component is called [NavigationContainer](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/).

Hence, the following should fix the issue.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Localisation from './localisation';
import Home from './home';

const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator()

const AppNavigator = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Navigator  initialRouteName="Home">
      <Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Home" component={Home} />
    </Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
 
)

export default AppNavigator;
```